# Get the frequency and running total sum, running total sum percentage in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have two following dataframes df1, df2:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'col1':['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'],'col2':[1,2,3,4,3]}
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df1
  col1  col2
0    d     1
1    c     2
2    b     3
3    a     4
4    a     3
>>> df2=pd.DataFrame(data=['a','b','c', 'd'], columns=['col'])
>>> df2
  col
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to add three new columns to df2 to add value counts , total running sum, total running sum percentage for each of the element in df2.col i.e. (a,b,c,d).

Here is what I got so far, but I feel the process should be easier than what I have done. Also, I am not sure how to calculate the total running percentage.

```
>>> a=df1.col1.value_counts(dropna=False)
>>> a
a    2
d    1
c    1
b    1
>>> b=df1.groupby("col1").sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum()
>>> b
      col2
col1
a        7
b        3
c        2
d        1

>>> df3=pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
>>> df3=df3.reset_index()
>>> df3
  index  col1  col2
0     a     2     7
1     d     1     1
2     c     1     2
3     b     1     3
>>> new_dataset
  col index  col1  col2
0   a     a     2     7
1   b     b     1     3
2   c     c     1     2
3   d     d     1     1
```

Expected out should be:

```
>>> new_dataset
  col index  col1  col2  col3
0   a     a     2     7  0.54
1   b     b     1     3  0.23
2   c     c     1     2  0.15
3   d     d     1     1  0.08
```

Comment: Do you have a `d` in `df2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes thanks for pointing it out. Just edited the post again.

Comment: Also, what's the expected output in this case here?

Comment: @QuangHoang expected output added

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby`:

```
(df2.merge(df1.groupby('col1', as_index=False)['col2'].agg(['size','sum']),
          left_on='col',right_on='col1', how='left'
         )
  .assign(col3=lambda x: x['sum']/x['sum'].sum())
)
```

Output:

```
  col  size  sum      col3
0   a     2    7  0.538462
1   b     1    3  0.230769
2   c     1    2  0.153846
3   d     1    1  0.076923
```